# Recursively convert media directory from HEVC to h.264 with ffmpeg

Tags: macos, perl, recursion, ffmpeg, mkv

I have media server with two directories: Movies and TV Shows. Within each of those directories, each entry exists in a sub-directory which contains the video file and subtitle files.

I've scoured the web and have found an excellent perl script from Michelle Sullivan, posted here:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open DIR, "ls -1 |";
while (<DIR>)
{
        chomp;
        next if ( -d "$_"); # skip directories
        next unless ( -r "$_"); # if it's not readable skip it!
        my $file = $_;
        open PROBE, "ffprobe -show_streams -of csv '$file' 2>/dev/null|" or die ("Unable to launch ffmpeg for $file! ($!)");
        my ($v, $a, $s, @c) = (0,0,0);
        while (<PROBE>)
        {
                my @streaminfo = split(/,/, $_);
                push(@c, $streaminfo[2]) if ($streaminfo[5] eq "video");
                $a++ if ($streaminfo[5] eq "audio");
                $s++ if ($streaminfo[5] eq "subtitle");
        }
        close PROBE;
        $v = scalar @c;
        if (scalar @c eq 1 and $c[0] eq "ansi")
        {
                warn("Text file detected, skipping...\n");
                next;
        }
        warn("$file: Video Streams: $v, Audio Streams: $a, Subtitle Streams: $s, Video Codec(s): " . join (", ", @c) . "\n");
        if (scalar @c > 1)
        {
                warn("$file has more than one video stream, bailing!\n");
                next;
        }
        if ($c[0] eq "hevc")
        {
                warn("HEVC detected for $file ...converting to AVC...\n");
                system("mkdir -p h265");
                my @params = ("-hide_banner", "-threads 2");
                push(@params, "-map 0") if ($a > 1 or $s > 1 or $v > 1);
                push(@params, "-c:a copy") if ($a);
                push(@params, "-c:s copy") if ($s);
                push(@params, "-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p") if ($v);
                if (system("mv '$file' 'h265/$file'"))
                {
                        warn("Error moving $file -> h265/$file\n");
                        next;
                }
                if (system("ffmpeg -xerror -i 'h265/$file' " . join(" ", @params) . " '$file' 2>/dev/null"))
                {
                        warn("FFMPEG ERROR.  Cannot convert $file restoring original...\n");
                        system("mv 'h265/$file' '$file'");
                        next;
                }
        } else {
                warn("$file doesn't appear to need converting... Skipping...\n");
        }
}
close DIR;
```

The script performs perfectly - as long as it is run from within the directory containing the media.

My question: Can this script be modified to run recursively from the root directory? How?

Thanks in advance.

(Michelle's script can be seen here: http://www.michellesullivan.org/blog/1636)

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html   You'd put the code in the loop above as the \&wanted prameter.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking, and all that you show is someone else's code. You say you've *"scoured the web"* to find this Perl program, and you now seem to be scouring it again to find free of charge something that I would guess you're incapable of creating for yourself. Stack Overflow is a place where programmers who are blocked by a *specific problem* can ask their peers for help. It is not intended that an ignoramus can dump their requirements here and wait for a solution

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to run recursively? Do you mean that you want to run it on all the files under a particular directory?

In this problems, I'd rather separate the part that generates the list of files to process from the processing. With a long list of files, I might take the lines from standard input instead:

```
while( <> ) {
    ...
    }
```

Pipe the list into the script:

```
$ find ... | script
```

Or take it from a file:

```
$ script list_of_files.txt
```

With a short list, I might use a favorite xargs trick:

```
$ find ... -print0 | xargs -0 script
```

In that case I go through the command-line arguments:

```
 foreach ( @ARGV ) {
    ...
    }
```

If you want to do all of this in the program, you can use [File::Find](http://www.metacpan.org/module/File::Find).

Beyond that, it sounds like you are asking someone to do the work for you.